# Evenly space Plotly.js timestamp values

Tags: javascript, plotly

I have a Plotly chart where I plot some points based on some sensor values (x axis) and the time that value arrived (timestamp - y axis).

The problem is that I receive the values randomly, sometimes a couple of measurements in one second, and sometimes another measurements after a couple of hours.

This causes the chart not to be scaled evenly, which makes sense.

[image]

What I would like to achieve is the following: all timestamp values (y axis) should be evenly spaced, and not taking into account the time passed between them.

Is this possible?

Edit: I tried using timestamps as strings, but this causes some weird functionality when using two traces, they won't overlap as they should).

[image]